# Creating a generic notification service

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, .net

I'm trying to create a generic notification service that works with

1. Mail (smtp )
2. Sms (Third part vendor)
3. Push events (For future)

> Purpose : Create a notification service and it should be pluggable

A Common interface for all notification service

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    bool Notify();
}
```

Mail Service

```
public class MailService : INotificationService
{
    readonly string address;
    readonly string subject;
    readonly string message;

    public MailService(string adrss, string subject, string mesg)
    {
        this.address = adrss;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.message = mesg;
    }

    public bool Notify()
    {
        //pseudo code
        Console.WriteLine("Email service invoked " + address + subject + message);
        return true;

    }
}
```

**Sms Service**

```
public class SmsService : INotificationService
{
    readonly string phoneNumber;
    readonly string message;
    readonly ISmsSender sender;
    public SmsService(string phone, string msg, ISmsSender send)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = phone;
        this.message = msg;
        this.sender = send;
    }

    public bool Notify()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sms service invoked" + phoneNumber, message);
        return sender.SendSms(message);

    }
}
```

**ISms Sender interface** Mocking third party sms service

```
public interface ISmsSender
{
    bool SendSms(string msg);
}

public class SmsSender : ISmsSender
{
    public bool SendSms(string msg)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Consuming program**

```
 INotificationService smsNotification = new 
                                       SmsService("12346789", "content" ,new SmsSender());
smsNotification.Notify();


INotificationService mailNotification = 
                                   new MailService("mail@gmail.com", "subject", "content");
mailNotification.Notify();
```

Please find the source code and have added couple of unit test [here](https://github.com/eldhoabe/NotificationService/tree/master)

**Questions**

1. Is it a good design or Any better design
2. Based on the code coverage still 42% are not covered.
3. Passing all necessary arguments in the constructor have any impact on maintainability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I'd say it's a good design. You use dependency injection and provide all required parameters via the constructor. You also use an abstraction (interface) for the service but... it's not very useful.

---

Why do you need an `INotificationService`? To be able to send notifications without knowing how they are going to be sent. You receive a notification-service and want to call the `Notify` method to send a notification. But do you want to repeatedly send the same notification? I don't think so. Thus the `Notify` method should probably require a message that you want to send.

---

I can imagine that such a service would have this API. You don't return `bool` but nothing if it worked and throw an exception if it didn't. If you don't throw exceptions then the user cannot know what went wrong if a service wasn't able to send a notification.

```
public interface INotificationService
{
    void Notify(string subject, string message);
}
```

Not all services may support a subject but a subject and a message are the two properties that actually every notification has.

---

Now the mail-service needs only the address (don't abbreviate names like *adress*):

```
public class MailService : INotificationService
{
    readonly string _address;

    public MailService(string address)
    {
        _address = address;       
    }

    public void Notify(string subject, string message)
    {
        // send notification
    }
}
```

The sms-service requires only the phone number and the sms-sender:

```
public class SmsService : INotificationService
{
    readonly string _phoneNumber;
    readonly ISmsSender sender;
    public SmsService(string phone, ISmsSender sender)
    {
        _PhoneNumber = phone;
        _sender = sender;
    }

    public void Notify(string subject, string message)
    {
        // send notification
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> var smsNotification = new SmsService("12346789", "content" ,new SmsSender());
> ```

You shouldn't mix the vocabulary. If you create a `SmsService` then the instance is a `smsService` and not a `smsNotification` although in this case it is technically a notification because it can only send a single message over and over again. If this is the desired behavior then you shouldn't call it an `INotificationService` but an `INotification`. The names need to be clear otherwise the usage of your API is very confusing.

---

Ok, with the new design both services can still send messages but you can send a new message each time instead creating a new instance just to send a new message - so they are now *real* notification-services and not just notifications.

```
var smsService = new SmsService("12346789", new SmsSender());
smsService.Notify("Test1", "This is a message");
smsService.Notify("Test2", "This is another message");
```

Comment: i have another concern about this design. I'm consuming notification service in web api. Where could i inject the `INotificationSevice` if i do in constructor the data that are subject wont be available there. i.e, My api method is like this `bool SendOtp(string phoneNumber)` its http-post method.

Comment: i have added detailed question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152414/consuming-a-generic-notification-service . pls take a review @t3chbot